# Unable to customize Kendo-Window in Angular

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-window

I am using Kendo UI for Angular and I am trying to change the color of the header to a custom color, but I am unable to.

I am trying to override the default color with blue and added the below code to my component's css file.

```
/deep/ .k-window-titlebar * {
           background-color:blue !important;
}
```

And this what I am getting.
[image]

I want to change this to blue completely. I am a novice web developer and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the `*` in your css-selector.

With the selector `.k-window-titlebar *` you are styling the elements **within** the `.k-window-titlebar`, but in your case you want to style the `.k-window-titlebar` **itself**.

```
/deep/ .k-window-titlebar {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/GyRoU6Tmtq1lvgap0DkT?p=preview)